# Differentiate retina and non-retina display in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, retina-display

I am trying to check retina/non-retina display as following in viewDidLoad method

It is working fine to adjust layout for both display.

```
BOOL isRetina = FALSE;

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        isRetina = TRUE;
    } else {
        isRetina = FALSE;
    }
}

if (isRetina) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
}
```

It is working fine in xcode 5 but getting error at the time of building in xcode 4

Error as following

```
Property 'edgesForExtendedLayout' not found on object of type 'FirstViewController *'
```

How can solve it.

Comment: There is little point to see if the scale property exists. It's been around for a while. I is unlikely you need to support a version of iOS where it didn't exist. Check the docs to be sure.

Comment: And why are you tying retina or not with the edgesForExtendedLayout setting? They have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: And lastly, why are you using both Xcode 4 and 5 to build the same code?

Answer (score 1):

`edgesForExtendedLayout` property is only in iOS7+. You should conditionally check the OS version also. If it is below iOS7 it will throw error.The device of retina doesn't mean that it is running on iO7. Checking the availability of method is more accurate as suggest by rmaddy

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: No, do not check the version of iOS. Th proper thing is to check if th method exists.

Answer (score 1):

`edgesForExtendedLayout` is added on iOS7, so it will be available only in Base SDK 7.0 which is bundled with Xcode 5.

Your Xcode 4 will be using a base sdk version lower than iOS 7.

see class reference of [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your Error it self answer `edgesForExtendedLayout` is only available in iOS 7.0 or later. You can check for it at run-time using something like

you can simply put this code:-

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
{
    [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone];
}
```

instead of check retina or non-retina you need to check iOS version like:-

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

        // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier

    } else {

       self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
       self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
       self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;

    }

#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_4_0  751.32
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_4_1  751.37
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_4_2  751.49
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_4_3  751.49
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_5_0  881.00
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_5_1  890.10
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_0  993.00
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1  993.00
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, `edgesForExtendedLayout` only became available with iOS 7. Nitin's answer should help you circumvent the compilation error.

If you want to support lower iOS versions, you should compile in Xcode 5 using the iOS 7 SDK but conditionally define how you want to render views.

Refer to Apple's docs on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW3

Answer (score -1):

```
try this

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] &&
([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
{
// Retina display
NSLog(@"---------------Retina display");
} else {
// non-Retina display
NSLog(@"---------------non-Retina display");
}
```

Comment: Why are you checking for the `displayLinkWithTarget:selector:` method? That has nothing to do with whether it is a retina device or not. Besides, what does this have to do with the problem in the original question?

Answer (score -2):

Please use this code if you want to use edgesForExtendedLayout property because this is ios7 property for manage the layout.

```
NSString *reqSysVer @"7.0"
NSString *currSysVer [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
BOOL isRetina = FALSE;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
        isRetina = TRUE;
    } else {
        isRetina = FALSE;
    }
}
if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending){
    if (isRetina) {
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to handle this. Please see the answer by Anil for the proper way. You should always check for the existence of the property, method, or class if possible. Only check the OS version when there is no other possible way.